# How to handle the error in a sequelize ORM query statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, backend

I am using Sequelize ORM in Node/Express with Typescript.

I have 'users' table with unique column 'email'

I am writing singIn api and contemplating which method would be better.

1. use single CREATE query and then catch error

```
export const signup = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    console.log('requset: ', req.body);
    const user = await User.create(req.body);
    res.send('Successfully Created');
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ValidationError) {
      if (error.errors.map((err) => err.type).includes('unique violation')) {
        res.status(409).send(`${req.body.email} is alreay in use`);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

2. First, checking for duplicates using the SELECT query and then creating using the CREATE query.

```
export const signup = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const duplicate = await User.count({ where: { email: req.body.email } });
    if (duplicate > 0) {
      res.status(409).send(`${req.body.email} is alreay in use`);
    } else {
      const user = await User.create(req.body);
      console.log('User created:', user.toJSON());
      res.send('Successfully Created');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

What's the better pattern?

Comment: add unique constrain to email column in database level so any duplicate value will be throw an error at the database level

Comment: thank you for reply. I added unique constraint on the email column and db emit duplicate error when I execute wrong query. both way on the question works well, but I am curious which way is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findOrCreate` and check either a record was created or not and return an error if it already exists:

```js
export const signup = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const [user, isCreated] = await User.findOrCreate({
     where: { email: req.body.email },
     defaults: req.body 
    });
    if (!isCreated) {
      res.status(409).send(`${req.body.email} is already in use`);
      return;
    }
    console.log('User created:', user.toJSON());
    res.send('Successfully Created');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```